clang offsetof with struct inheritance in c programming
I'm trying to make the following code work compiling with clang*, any help?
  typedef struct A {
    int value;
  } A;

  typedef struct B {
    A;
  } B;

  int main (void) {
    offsetof(B,A);
  return 0;
  }

*I've no problem using gcc using the plan9-exentions

Clang does not support the Plan9 extensions. So typedef struct B { A; } B; already doesn't work, regardless of offsetof.

By the way, if your code doesn't compile, it probably produced an error. Please [edit] your question to include that error as code-formatted text so we can see it.

Clang does not support the Plan9 C extensions at all.
